# fedora desktop - is turning off ssh tunnel secure for regular user

Tags: ssh, fedora

I have turned off all remote clients So - Is turning off ssh secure i.e. my ssh is dead now.

if I am accessing internet as regular; Is it an essential for security or dead is better

Comment: i'm pretty sure you're going to need to provide more information for anyone to actually help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ssh* is a very secure protocol, under certain conditions. In fact, I am unaware of any existing weaknesses,as of now. However, to be totally frank, you must remember that password login is **not** safe. The reason is that passwords are exchanged in clear (*i.e.*, unencrypted) form. Also, there are currently excellent programs for serially testing passwords  at an amazingly fast pace.

Thus, you can make *ssh* very secure by means of four wise configuration choices:

1. Disable root login;
2. Change port, picking a port beyond 10000. This will at least keep the casual peruser away from your pc, even though it will not deter determined attackers;
3. Enable cryptographic keys (DSA better than RSA) for client authentication;
4. Disable password authentication completely.

(Make sure point 2 works before proceeding to point 3, or you may risk having logged yourself out of your pc permanently, if it is a remote machine for instance).

With these three choices, and barring extra nasty surprises from *OpenSSL*, you should be reasonably safe.

Comment: so actually i thought i being tracked by someone else so I disabled all remote services but it seems something different issue; so by disabling ssh i will be not secure.

Comment: thank you very much so great i ve disabled root  sbin nologin and i know recovery, there's no issue for me. but booting takes 10 minutes of time can you please guide.

Comment: @RahulChavan Any hint from *dmesg*?

Comment: userspace takes 20 minutes

Comment: @RahulChavan I am sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: total boot time $ systemd-analyze:==>
Startup finished in 643ms (kernel) + 1.970s (initrd) + 20min 18.076s (userspace) = 20min 20.691s

Comment: 1. total boot time $ systemd-analyze:==> Startup finished in 643ms (kernel) + 1.970s (initrd) + 20min 18.076s (userspace) = 20min 20.691s                                                              2. hello please I can access SU FOR fedora software center and packekit - how so.. does it crackED BY HACKER OR MY DOUBT.[ no terminal SU access ] iF I WANT LOCK ROOT EVERYWHERE THEN WHAT TO DO. KINDLY GUIDE